# JAVA - Вывод List в Label/SWT

Tags: java, list, label, swt

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо вывести элементы из List на Label, вывожу в цикле, остается только последний элемент. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

```
    Label lblNewLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel.setText("Hit the Send button to get a response.");
    GridData gd_lblNewLabel = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1);
    gd_lblNewLabel.widthHint = 426;
    gd_lblNewLabel.heightHint = 162;
    lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel);

    btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Object> srcLister = new ArrayList<Object>();
            LoadWeb l = new LoadWeb();
            l.loadString();
            l.saveFile();
            srcLister = l.parseXML();

            for(int i = 0; i < srcLister.size(); i++) {
                lblNewLabel.setText(srcLister.get(i).toString());
                System.out.println(srcLister.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `label.setText(string)` устанавливает значение, которое вы передаете в `string`, а не добавляет его к уже существующему. Можете поступить следующим образом:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(srcLister.size());
for(int i = 0; i < builder.size(); i++) {
    builder.append(srcLister.get(i).toString());
}
lblNewLabel.setText(builder.toString());
```

**Лучше использовать StringBuilder вместо String, так как конкатенация довольно "дорогая" операция.**